# Torus is the only closed orientable surface regularly covered by punctured plane

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, covering-spaces, free-groups

> Let $\Sigma_g$ be the closed orientable surface of genus $g$. There is
> **no** covering map $p\colon\Bbb R^2\backslash \mathbf 0\to \Sigma_g$ so that $p_*\pi_1(\Bbb R^2\backslash \mathbf 0)$ is a **normal** subgroup
> of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ when $g\geq 2$. In other words, the fundamental group of any
> closed orientable hyperbolic surface has no normal infinite cyclic subgroup.

***Attempt:*** Suppose, we have a normal covering $\Bbb R^2\backslash \mathbf 0\to \Sigma_g$, where $g\geq 2$. So, there is an infinite cyclic normal subgroup of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$. In other words, we have non-trivial elements $a,b\in \pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ such that $bab^{-1}=a^n$ for some integer $n$. Consider the subgroup $G$ of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ generated by $a,b$ and let $X\to \Sigma_g$ be the covering corresponding to the subgroup $G$ of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$. Note that $X$ is an orientable surface as $\Sigma_g$ is an orientable surface. Also, $\pi_1(X)=G$.

$\textbf{Case 1:}$ Let $X$ be compact. From classification theory $X\cong \Sigma_h$ for some $h\geq 0$. So, the covering will be finite-fold, say $m$-fold, and then $2-2h=\chi(X)=m\cdot \chi(\Sigma_g)=m(2-2g)$, i.e., $1+m(g-1)=h$, i.e. $h\geq 2$. In other words, $\pi_1(\Sigma_h)=G$ is generated by two elements, in particular, $\Bbb Z^{2h}\cong \frac{G}{[G,G]}$ is also generated by two elements when $h\geq 2$, a contradiction. *So, this case is impossible.*

$\textbf{Case 2:}$ Let $X$ be non-compact. Hence, $\pi_1(X)=G$ is a free group. Also, from hypothesis, $G$ is generated by $a,b$ such that $bab^{-1}=a^n\implies a=(b^{-1}ab)^n$. ........

Now, if I show that the problem can be started by assuming that $a$ is not a proper power of some element, then  $a=(b^{-1}ab)^n$ gives $n=\pm 1$. When $n=1$ we have $ab=ba$, and in a free group, if two non-trivial elements commute, then they are powers of some common element, i.e., $a=b^{\pm 1}$ as $a$ is not a proper power of any element, and this ends up with giving that every element of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ is a power of $a$, impossible.

> But I don't know how to tackle the case $n=-1$, also how to show the
> problem can be started by assuming $a$ is not a proper power of any
> element.

Comment: For the $n=1$ case, use $b^2$ in place of $b$, as $b^{-2}ab^2=a$.

Comment: (In general though, I'm slightly confused by the question in the sense that I'm unsure what "tools" you have access too. It would help if you said which book, for example, it comes from, or just what theorems you might be expected to apply in the proof.)

Comment: Actually, I am reading $\text{Proposition 5.2.}$ of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.14266.pdf where it is written that *'' the fundamental group of a hyperbolic surface cannot have a normal cyclic subgroup''*. I expect more or less clearcut proof or idea using any tools from algebraic topology or group theory. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Oh right, so anything is allowed? Then in the finite-index case you can use the fact that any torsion-free group with a cyclic subgroup of finite index is necessarily infinite cyclic, while for the infinite-index case you can use the fact that all infinite-index subgroups of surface groups are free, so if $\langle a\rangle$ is your normal subgroup then for all $b\in \pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ we have $\langle a, b\rangle$ is free, but satisfies the relation $b^{-1}ab=a^n$ for some $n$ so cannot be free of rank two, and hence is cyclic, and so $a$ and $b$ commute...

Comment: ...therefore, $\langle a\rangle$ is central in $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$. However, centralisers of elements in $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ are cyclic, so $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ is cyclic, a contradiction. QED (I've not made this an answer as I'm not sure how helpful this proof is, as I'm unsure where to find proofs of some of these facts!)

Comment: OK, I've typed up a more general proof. I'll see if I can find the appropriate references at somepoint soon (fact (2) will be in Bridson+Haefliger's book "metric spaces of nonpositive curvature", while fact (1) should follow from Euler characteristic stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give an algebraic proof, which is actually quite general. In particular, surface groups of genus $\geq2$ are torsion-free and hyperbolic.

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a torsion-free hyperbolic group. If $G$ contains an infinite cyclic normal subgroup, then $G$ is itself cyclic.

Your result follows as surface groups of genus $\geq2$ are non-cyclic.

*Proof.*
We need the following two useful, and standard facts: (1) For all $x\in G$, the centraliser $C_G(x)$ is infinite cyclic. (2) If a torsion-free group $H$ contains a finite-index cyclic subgroup, then $H$ is itself cyclic.

Let $\langle a\rangle$ be an infinite cyclic normal subgroup of $G$. Let $b\in G$ be arbitrary. As $\langle a\rangle\lhd G$, the element $b$ acts on $\langle a\rangle$ as an automorphism, and so $b^2$ centralises $a$. By fact (1), $\langle a, b^{2}\rangle$ is cyclic. Now, $\langle a, b^{2}\rangle$ is normal in $\langle a, b\rangle$, and so infact has index $2$ in this subgroup. Hence, by fact (2), $\langle a, b\rangle$ is cyclic, and in particular $a$ and $b$ commute. As $b$ was arbitrary, $a\in Z(G)$. By fact (1), we have that $G$ is cyclic as required.